# Stopping condition in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I haven't been able to find much on this - likely because GEE prefers the use of .map and such. However, I have an inherently iterative problem. At a high level, I just need to iterate through a list and stop once a condition is met. This can easily be done with client-side operations. But I have not been able to figure out the GEE equivalent to this.

Pseudocode (client-side) for what I want to do:

```
orderedList = [1,2,3,4,5]
answer = null
for element in orderedList:
    if element satisfies condition:
        answer = element
        break
```

Comment: Short answer is, you cannot do it in that way, though there are usually ways to solve the same types of problems as you would with an iterate/break, using server-side functions. Which way fits best depends on the specifics of your problem. The way you wrote your pseudo-code,  you could consider using a filter, then a reduction with a max reducer. I would suggest that you update your questions with more details on the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Daniel's comment -- I would say the answer to this is on a case-by-case basis. I some cases, you will find that [ee.List.iterate](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-iterate) or the image-based equivalent [ee.ImageCollection.iterate](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-iterate) will let you achieve what you want. You can start by looking at the example from the documentation for [List](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-iterate#code-editor-javascript-sample) and [ImageCollection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_iterating).

Here's the example for List, but I added one condition to "break" the iteration. However, note that it isn't really "breaking" the iteration, but simply adjusting the result of the iteration based on the condition (all elements after iteration 14 are the same). You can get the result from the last item in the list.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e6f00efe61c6f970ddebae6830b6c394

```js
// This example uses the ee.List.iterate function to generate a series of
// sequentially halved values.

// Declare a list that will hold the series of sequentially halved values,
// initialize it with the starting quantity.
var quantityList = [1000];

// Define the number of iterations as a list sequence.
var nSteps = ee.List.sequence(1, 20);

var eps = 0.05; // Condition: |n_i - n_{i-1}| <= eps

// Declare a function that takes the current element of the iteration list and
// the returned result of the previous iteration as inputs. In this case, the
// the function is returning an accumulating list of quantities that are reduced
// by half at each iteration.
var halfOfPrevious = function(currentElement, previousResult) {
  var previousQuantity = ee.Number(ee.List(previousResult).get(-1));
  var currentQuantity = previousQuantity.divide(2);
  var delta = currentQuantity.subtract(previousQuantity);
  var condition = delta.abs().gt(eps);
  currentQuantity = ee.Algorithms.If(condition, currentQuantity, previousQuantity);
  return ee.List(previousResult).add(currentQuantity);
};

// Apply the function to the nSteps list, each element is an iteration.
quantityList = ee.List(nSteps.iterate(halfOfPrevious, quantityList));
print('Result: ', quantityList.get(-1)) // Last item in list is the result. 

// Display the results. Note that step 0 is included for the initial value.
print('Steps in the iteration of halved quantities', nSteps);
print('Series of sequentially halved quantities', quantityList);
print(ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: quantityList,
  axis: 0,
  xLabels: ee.List([0]).cat(nSteps)
}));
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the example. I'll post a more in-depth question if I can't figure it out with this new knowledge.